# WebExecute - HoverElement

Tags: webtools

In the course of getting data from Barchart ( https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AAPL ) , I come across the cmd of HoverElement in WebExecute.

In particular, I want to select between Options Prices and Volatility & Greeks under OPTIONS.

Appreciate if some one can share with me a basic example involving HoverElement ?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the API is basically exposed in their HTML. Have you tried that? That will be _way_ easier to work with

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used WebExecute LocateElement either based on XPath or CSS Selector to select. And then use ClickElement. But the result is unstable. So if I were to use API method, what will be appropriate command to use ?

Comment: @Akcmok please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts